# Authentication error while loading data from SA360 WebQuery to BigQuery

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am working on a project where our goal is to load data from Google's Search Ads 360(SA360) to our data warehouse.

As per Google's suggestion, the best way to accomplish this is using this [Java Application](https://github.com/google/sa360-webquery-bigquery) (This link has the code and step-by-step instructions). This Java application is Java code( Jar file) which extracts data from SA360 WebQuery in XML format and parses it into CSV format and loads it into our BigQuery tables.

I followed step-by-step instructions mentioned in the link but I am getting the following error listed below. When I tried to debug the code, I found that the 'Credential' is being passed as null in the code.

**ERROR:**

```
Sep 10, 2020 4:50:32 PM dswebquerytobigquery.Main main
INFO: config file: sample-config.csv
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dswebquerytobigquery.Authorizer.refreshAndStoreCredential(Authorizer.java:58)
        at dswebquerytobigquery.Authorizer.authorize(Authorizer.java:51)
        at dswebquerytobigquery.Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

Can any one please let me know how to properly create OAuth 2.0 Client ID credential in Google BigQuery? I think the credential is causing this issue.

Comment: Can you explain how did you configure your credentials?

Comment: Hi @R.Esteves, looks like the issue was with the code. I reached out to the google developer who created this application and he fixed it.
To answer your question, I have created a credential for OAuth 2.0 Client ID with an Application Type of Desktop.
For this application to work, the credential should be of Installed application type.

Comment: Is the problem completely solved?